# How to double check if folder is empty`?

Tags: vb.net

I can't find a solution for my problem. My Code is deleting empty folders and in general working fine, but there is one exception. It goes through every path one time, but if there was a Folder (A) that only has empty Folder (B) in it, then it would only delete Folder(B), since Folder (A) was not at empty at the time. How can I make it, so that it understands that Folder (A) is gonna be empty, once Folder (B) is deleted?

I thought `DeleteEmptyFolder(folder.FullName)` would solve the problem, but it is not working, since it doesn't repeat the same path it already went through. Removing `directory.GetDirectories.Count = 0` doesn't work either, since it would delete any folder that doesn't have a file in it (even if there is another folder with files in it)

```
Private Sub DeleteEmptyFolder(ByVal sDirectoryPath As String)

            If IO.Directory.Exists(sDirectoryPath) Then
                Dim directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo(sDirectoryPath)
                If directory.GetDirectories.Count = 0 AndAlso directory.GetFiles.Count = 0 Then
                    directory.Delete(True)
                    Return
                End If
                For Each folder As IO.DirectoryInfo In directory.GetDirectories()
                    DeleteEmptyFolder(folder.FullName)
                Next
           End If
End Sub
```

I am fairly new to VB.Net, so pardon if it is an obvious answer that I don't see.

Comment: Let me have a better understanding of your final goal. You want to pass a folder path to your function and it searches through all folders and sub folders and delete empty ones and finally if the main folder contains nothing, deletes itself as well. Am I right?

Comment: It basically should delete all empty folders, including the one that get empty during the process

Answer (score 1):

Here's how the code ought to look:

```vb
Private Sub DeleteEmptyFolder(folderPath As String)
    If Directory.Exists(folderPath) Then
        For Each subFolderPath In Directory.EnumerateDirectories(folderPath)
            DeleteEmptyFolder(subFolderPath)
        Next

        If Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath).Any() OrElse
           Directory.EnumerateDirectories(folderPath).Any() Then
            Return
        End If

        Directory.Delete(folderPath)
    End If
End Sub
```

There's no point using `DirectoryInfo` if you need no other information about files and folders other than path. You should use `EnumerateFiles` and `EnumerateDirectories` over `GetFiles` and `GetDirectories` unless you specifically need to get an array of entries up front. In this case, you definitely don't. Let's say that you had a folder with 1000 files in it. This:

```vb
directory.GetFiles.Count = 0
```

would create an array containing an element for all 1000 files first, then check the number of elements in it. On the other hand, this:

```vb
Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath).Any()
```

would return `True` as soon as it encountered the first file, ignoring the other 999. You only care whether there's any files in the folder, not how many there are.

Comment: I thought of `Any`, too, listing down to answers. 

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
    Private Sub deleteEmptyFolders(ByRef folder As String)

        'Does exist such a path?
        If IO.Directory.Exists(folder) Then 'yes

            'Loop over all directories
            For Each subFolder In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(folder)

                'Delete all empty folders
                deleteEmptyFolders(subFolder)
            Next

            'Delete folder if nothing remained in it
            Try
                My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(folder, FileIO.DeleteDirectoryOption.ThrowIfDirectoryNonEmpty)
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```

I think this does what you want in a simple way.

Comment: A method parameter without a type is bad code. You should always have `Option Strict On`. Also, there's no justification for that parameter to be declared `ByRef`.

Comment: You're right about the type. I'd missed it. But about the ```ByRef```, in general, when you do not change the input, there is no need to make a copy of that. Hence, it is better to pass it by reference to not creating a copy of the input.

Comment: "when you do not change the input" <- Interesting point of view. I generally avoid `ByRef` unless I NEED the value to return changed. It is to prevent issues down the line when the code is many layers deep.

Comment: You are absolutely wrong about `ByRef`. This is not VB6. You need to learn the difference between value types and reference types. When you pass by value, a copy of the variable's contents is created. For reference types, the variable contents is a reference to an object, not the object itself, so no copy will be made of that object. That's the whole point of reference types. `ByVal` is the default for a reason. For reference types (classes and delegates) the ONLY time you pass by reference is if you want to set the parameter itself inside the method and have that reflected outside the method.

Comment: And note that even though strings act more like values than references (unlike with a "normal" reference type, changing `folder` within the routine won't be seen outside of it), they still *are* references and will not make a copy when passed to a `ByVal` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by moving some of the code around.

```
        Private Sub DeleteEmptyFolder(ByVal sDirectoryPath As String)

                If IO.Directory.Exists(sDirectoryPath) Then
                    Dim directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo(sDirectoryPath)
                    For Each folder As IO.DirectoryInfo In directory.GetDirectories()
                        DeleteEmptyFolder(folder.FullName)
                    Next
                    If directory.GetDirectories.Count = 0 AndAlso directory.GetFiles.Count = 0 Then
                        directory.Delete(True)
                        Return
                    End If
                End If
            End If
```